# Holding strong reference to Picasso Target does not work

Tags: android, android-fragments, bitmap, picasso

I am using `Picasso` to add an `icon` to my `actionbar`. I've read that in order to load the image every time I need to make my `Target` of `strong reference` and for that I've used `final`. But, again, it goes into `onPrepareLoad` and never reaches `onBitmapLoaded`.
What am I doing wrong?

```
private void setLogoToActionBar() {
    final Target target = new Target() {
        @Override
        public void onBitmapLoaded(Bitmap bitmap, Picasso.LoadedFrom from) {
            Log.d("DEBUG", "onBitmapLoaded");
            Drawable d = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), bitmap);
            actionBar.setIcon(d);
        }

        @Override
        public void onBitmapFailed(Drawable errorDrawable) {
            Log.d("DEBUG", "onBitmapFailed");
        }

        @Override
        public void onPrepareLoad(Drawable placeHolderDrawable) {
            Log.d("DEBUG", "onPrepareLoad");
            actionBar.setIcon(placeHolderDrawable);
        }
    };
    Picasso.with(getContext()).load(mShop.getClientLogo()).placeholder(R.drawable.shop_asset).resize(100, 100).into(target);
}
```

Comment: You are declaring a local variable - `target` goes out of scope at the end of `setLogoToActionBar` and will GC'ed shortly thereafter. Use a member variable in the `Activity`/`Fragment` you are in.

Comment: Wow I can't believe it was so simple and how I've missed that. :<